# I am trying to merge two columns into one in the result set. How can i achieve this in Access

Tags: ms-access

I currently have a tbl_1 with 6 columns Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, ColPaid, ColDiff. ColPaid and ColDiff Should be in row1 and row2 as in the table below

```
Col1   Col2   Col3  Col4  ColPaid ColDiff  ColNew
==================================================
A       1       A    T     $15      $3      
B       2       B    Q     $20      $7
```

I would like Tbl_1 to appear as follows below:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3  Col4    ColPaid
=======================================
A       1       A    T        $15.00
A       1       A    T         $3.00
B       2       B    Q        $20.00
B       2       B    Q         $7.00
```

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A union query should be able to do this: `SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, colpaid FROM yourtable UNION ALL SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, coldiff FROM yourtable`

Comment: ...or a cross-tab query in Access

Comment: Don't see how crosstab could accomplish. UNION query, yes. Why would you want ColDiff data under ColPaid?

Comment: Official documentation: [Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Answer (score 1):

UNION query can rearrange fields to records.
First SELECT line determines data types and field names.
Can assign alias name and add a column to categorize the data.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, ColPaid AS Amount, "PD" AS Cat FROM yourtable 
UNION ALL SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, ColDiff, "DF" FROM yourtable;
```